# Tap IconButton in AppBar to display TextField floating over Scaffold body (with one widget, not two)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to float a box from a Widget in the `AppBar` over (above) the `Scaffold` body? For example, if I put my search Widget into the `Scaffold` body, when my search `IconButton` is tapped, this `TextField` appears and hangs over the content below it:

[image: Search icon with search input box]

However, ideally, I'd like the search icon to appear in the `AppBar` (not the `Scaffold` body), and then when tapped, I'd like the input box to float over the `Scaffold` body. If I put my Search Widget into the `AppBar`, the `TextField` is hidden under the `Scaffold` body, like this:

[image: Search icon in AppBar overflowing behind Scaffold]

If you look carefully, you can actually see the `TextField` focusedBorder after I tap in the small margin below the icon on the `AppBar` but above the `Scaffold` body:

[image: TextField border when tapped between AppBar and Scaffold]

So, you can see that the `TextField` is hidden behind the `Scaffold` body.

I discovered from the Flutter documentation that the `Scaffold` body puts its content below the `AppBar` and behind the `floatingActionButton` and `drawer` by design (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/body.html). However, using a `floatingActionButton` or a `drawer` for this use case would be a bit of a hack.

I suppose that I could have the `TextField` in a separate widget and located in the `Scaffold` body and use a `Provider`/`ChangeNotifier` to communicate to the widget in the `Scaffold` that the `IconButton` in the `AppBar` was tapped. But, that splits the component logic into two places, which seems messy.
I'm hoping someone can enlighten me with a best practice or set me in the right direction.

So, is there an appropriate way to have an `IconButton` in an `AppBar` display a `TextField` that floats over the `Scaffold` body? (It seems like it would be a common use case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Stack` for your `Scaffold > body`:

[image]

### Full source code:

```
import 'dart:math' show Random;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AppWidget());
}

class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => SearchModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Color(0xfffedbd0)),
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<SearchModel>(
      builder: (context, searchModel, child) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('SHRINE'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search, semanticLabel: 'search'),
                onPressed: () => searchModel.toggleVisibility()),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Search(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Search extends StatelessWidget {
  Search();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<SearchModel>(builder: (context, searchModel, child) {
      return Stack(
        children: [
          GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            children: List.generate(
              30,
              (index) => Container(
                color: Color(0xaaaa0000 + 0xffffff ~/ (index + 1)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: searchModel.isVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 190.0,
                  height: 25.0,
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (text) => searchModel.updateText(text),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}

class SearchModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  String text = '';
  bool isVisible = false;

  updateText(String newText) {
    text = newText;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  toggleVisibility() {
    isVisible = !isVisible;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like you're splitting the search icon into the AppBar separately from what goes into the scaffold body, but that implementation looks pretty clean since it still keeps the search logic in the SearchModel.